Datatype of the returned variable gets changed in the calling method
The datatype of assetId in method one() is Int64. But when I print the returned variable outside that method, the datatype is now an object.
function one(){        
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $finalizeUrl -Method 'POST' -Body $createResponse.Content -Headers @{"Authorization" = $authToken; "Content-Type" = "application/json" }    
    $responseObject = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json 
    
    $assetId = $responseObject.asset_id
    Write-Host $assetId
    Write-Host "Type of assetId in function one: " ($assetId.GetType().Name)
    return $assetId
}

$asset_id = one
Write-Host $asset_id
Write-Host "Type of asset_id outside one: " ($asset_id.GetType().Name)

Output:

140863
Type of assetId in function one:  Int64
{"success":true,"message":null} 140863
Type of asset_id outside function one:  Object[]

What am I doing wrong here.

one isnt returning anything to the success stream, don't see how this is possible unless there is something we're not seeing in your function

Why are you not forcefully typecasting it to Integer if you need that only? I strongly think that something we are missing in this function.

Put $assetid at the bottom of the one function, without write-host.

Sorry, I missed out the return statement. Updated the question now.

This looks like the default behavior in PowerShell, where the a returned variable isn't the same datatype outside the method.
I resolved this by using a global variable.
$global:asset_id = 0
function one(){        
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $finalizeUrl -Method 'POST' -Body $createResponse.Content -Headers @{"Authorization" = $authToken; "Content-Type" = "application/json" }    
    $responseObject = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json     
    $global:asset_id = $responseObject.asset_id    
}

one
Write-Host $global:asset_id
Write-Host "Type of asset_id outside one: " ($global:asset_id.GetType().Name)


I suggest using $script: instead of $global: as it will set the variable only for the script and will not leak outside of it. Setting it up before hand is also not necessary.

From the output, looks like the status message of the request were coupled with asset_id in your function return, hence it returns as an object. I think there could be some additional code in your actual code might have returned it. You can work around this by assigning the status message to another variable instead
$request_status, $asset_id = one

